# Does anyone know how to modify/disable the blinking power LED when OS enter into sleep mode?

Tags: sleep, acpi, led

Does anyone know how to modify/disable the blinking power LED when OS enter into sleep mode?
Or is it feasible to do this by using OS? 
Does the power LED only controlled by hardware?
Or OS could modify it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is generally controlled by hardware, though this is not standardized. Hardware control is definitely the most simple, although that hardware could be a BMC or microcontroller that could be accessed from the host. Long story short though: no, I don't think you can modify it.

That's my two cents, anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

I just removed the wire for the power led from the motherboard...
Not a nice solution, but the f*****g led is not blinkg anymore.